# git clone through http-backend

Tags: git, push

RPC failed; result=22; HTTP code = 401 with '@' in username

When I'm trying to use HTTP URLs and a username containing a `@` character with Git, I get RPC errors from `git push`.

For `git clone` I have to do the following:

```
git clone http://user%40domain.com@git_server/git_project
```

I replace the `@` in the username with `%40`, but `git push` doesn't work with this replacement.

How can I use a username with a `@` character with git's HTTP backend?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
git clone http://user%26%40domain.com:!password@git_server/git_project
```

Comment: No same result :

In apache log :
[error] [client IP] user user%26%40domain.com not found: /project/git-receive-pack